# Rails: Override 'Couldn't find Item with id=xxx' error to display flash error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, alert

In my program, I have to get product info using the product id, like this:

```
# Show the product info.
def show
    @product = Product.find params[:id]

    if !@product
        redirect_to products_path, :alert => 'Product not found!.'
    end
end
```

In case the product doesn't exist, I have a Rails error **Couldn't find Product with id=xxx**. I would like to override this error message and display the error by myself as a flash alert.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use begin rescue in your controller if only you have one change to be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `Product.try(:find, params[:id])` or `Product.find_by_id params[:id]` and get nil in case the product is not found instead of an exception

Comment: Indeed! find_by_id doesn't throw the exception. Then I just have to check if !product ... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

find method always raises ResourceNotFound.
If you want custom error message only for this action, you can do like that:

```
def show
    @product = Product.find_by_id params[:id]

    if @product.blank?
        redirect_to products_path, :alert => 'Product not found!.'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def show
    begin
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      redirect_to products_path, :alert => 'Product not found!.'
    end
end
```

Always try to rescue specific exception, this would give you desired result. As @Emrah mentioned `find` method will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when there is no record with given id.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method is specified to raise an error if nothing was found. You can use ARel style

```
@product = Product.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

instead, which will return `nil` on an empty result.